# convert python 3.x code to 2.x under python 2.7.9

Tags: python

I only have python 2.7.9 installed on my PC. I need to use a code written in 3.x. So I want to convert it to 2.x version syntax before executing it.

I saw "3to2" package, for example:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/3to2/1.0

However, it is said "This branch of 3to2 must be run with Python 3." in its "README" file.

So I wonder if it is possible to convert 3.x code to 2.x under python 2.7.9?

More specifically, I have `from html.parser import HTMLParser` in the script, which is only available in version 3. If I should use `from __future__ import`, how exactly should I do?

Comment: Why don't you just install python 3?

Comment: You'll want to have Python 3 installed to test the output of the 3to2 process works as expected. So you may as well install it first!

Comment: *I wonder if it is possible to convert 3.x code to 2.x ...?* **Yes**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `from html.parser import HTMLParser` to `from HTMLParser import HTMLParser`.